# Laravel Notification email per string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-notification

in my notifications i use the `(MailMessage)->markdown('<file>')` syntax and it works.

Not, i want to "inject" the markdown from outside, so i need something like this

`(MailMessage)->markdown("<string">);`

I think, you get the point.

When i now just give my markdown as a string to this function, it will not work and throws a

```
No hint path defined for [# Headline

Next line
```

error message.

So, how can i use string templates in my MailMessage markdown notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to put your markdown into a string as this is a bit counter-intuitive. The `markdown` method can only be used to specify the template path via dot notation - there is no current way to inject a markdown string.

However, what you could do is create a template that simply outputs whatever you pass to it (ie: the message/vars). For example:

`(MailMessage)->markdown('my.markdown.template', ['data' => "my string here with markdown and whatnot"]);`

Then, in your `my.markdown.template`, simply echo the data with nothing else: `{{ $data }}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The goal is to get a dynamic system of templates for emails. I want the customer to be able to store a template in the db and then fetch this template, parse the variables in it and email this template. Am i on the wrong track to do this with markdown() ???